# Using scrapy to extract raw html content of a large(r) number of landing pages

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

For a classification project I need the raw html content of roughly 1000 websites. I only need the landing page and not more, so the crawler does not have to follow links! I want to use scrapy for it but I can't get the code together. Because I read in the documentation that JSON Files are first stored in memory and then saved (which can cause Problems when crawling a large number of pages) I want to save the file in the '.js' format. I use the Anaconda promt to execute my code.

I want the resulting file to have two columns, one with the domainname, and the second with the raw_html content on every site

```
domain, html_raw
 ..., ...
 ..., ...
```

I found many Spider Examples but I cant figure out how to put everything together. This is how far I got :(

Start the Project:

```
scrapy startproject dragonball
```

The actuall Spider (which might be completely wrong):

```
import scrapy

class DragonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dragonball"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.faz.de',
            'https://www.spiegel.de',
            'https://www.stern.de',
            'https://www.brandeins.de',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        ???
```

I navigate to the dragonball Folder and execute the file with:

```
scrapy crawl dragonball -o dragonball.jl
```

Every help would be apreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to store everything in a single file, then you can use the following (including part of vezunchik's answer):

```
    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            'domain': urlparse(response.url).netloc,
            'html_raw': response.body.decode('utf-8'),
        }
```

As mentioned, this isn't a good idea in the long run as you'll end up with a huge file.

Comment: Oh yeah, it seems to work. Kick Ass :) I will now try my real list and see if it will work on scale. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to store html to files and write name of files to csv. It will be easier to keep data in format `domain, html_raw`.

You can download files with common `with open('%s.html' % domain, 'w') as f: f.write(response.body)` or download them with FILES pipeline, check documentation here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html

Domain you can get with:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
domain = urlparse(response.url).netloc
```

Comment: Thanks so far. But I have no clue how to implement what you suggest. Also, I need the data in one single file for my Algorithm, not multiple files. I know how to analyze data, but I never crawled before so I need a straigtforward solution which is why I chose scrapy and the way described in the documentation...

Comment: How do you plan to store everything to one file? Do you mean to the same csv with domains? Are you sure that it is comfortable to use it?